# Book series about aliens who put "caps" on people to control them

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I remember reading a series when I was around 7th or 8th grade about aliens who had taken over Earth by putting metal caps on people when they were "entering adulthood" to control them (not direct control, but it would keep them from rebelling). There was a faction of people who able to escape and had fake caps and would save teens who were about to be capped.

The main protagonist was a teen boy who was a boxer (or training to be a boxer or something). The aliens would hold tournaments for the humans and whoever won would be "worthy" to serve as personal slaves to the aliens.

> The protagonist won and was able to get inside to try and learn more about the aliens from the inside.

Comment: Wow I had no idea it was a TV series too. Although seeing the date (I wasn't born until a few years later) and that it is BBC I'm sure that's why I hadn't heard of it.

@Null Since he was looking for the TV series and I was looking for the books is it still considered duplicate since he got the books in his answer as well?  Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Yes, if another question includes an answer that answers your question then your question is a duplicate. There's nothing wrong with that, it's just to tie the duplicate questions together.

Comment: Cool, thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is John Christopher's [Tripods trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods). The protagonist is Will, who has grown up knowing only life under the alien Masters, however when he meets a wanderer named Ozymandias he learns of a world beyond their control.

The White Mountains details the story of Will's escape from England to the Alps.
The City of Gold and Lead details Will's infiltration of one of the Master's domed cities through his selection at an Olympics-like boxing contest, his learning that the Masters planned to replace Earth's atmosphere (toxic to them) with their own, and his subsequent escape.
The Pool of Fire sees a mass human uprising against the Masters, ending with the dome of one of their cities being shattered by grenades dropped from hot air balloons.

There is also (which I didn't know) a prequel called When The Tripods came.

In 1984/5 the BBC [adapted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_(TV_series)) the first two books; a third series was scripted but never produced.

All the books are available on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Tripods-Collection-White-Mountains/dp/1481415050/ref=pd_cp_b_0).

Comment: That's the series.  Thanks!

Comment: @kjw No probs. I also read them when I was a kid!